# Turtle Movement Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a network of turltes that each share two links. At the start of each turn the turtles decide to cooperate or defect, which updates a beta distribution of likelihood of cooperation in the next tick. If the turtles fail to cooperate over n turns they no longer interact. Through this I am able to create clusters in the cooperation network.

Right now, I am trying to figure out how to make the turtles move closer together proportional to the weight of their ties. Is there code to do this? I have only been able to find example code for patches.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. As the turtles have ties to multiple other turtles, there is no mathematical solution that lays out the turtles so each tie length is proportional to weight. Have you looked at the `layout-spring` primitive?

Answer (score 0):

I think this model might have something similar to what you want:
http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/3632#model_tabs_browse_procedures